# php working with array in single column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

**mysql database on phpmyadmin**

```
table_1: id, link

table_2: user_id, c_id
```

i have to store multiple values in `c_id` column in `table_2` which 
    refer to `id` column in `table_1`

how to write `UPDATE` queries to add new values to `c_id` column 
and also `SELECT` queries to access each `c_id` value and get link from `table_1`

also i need to write php APIs for the same

Comment: `UPDATE` queries change existing rows in the database.  `INSERT` is the query that adds new rows.  This question does not seem to indicate much effort on the part of the asker.  What have you tried, and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Change database design, it is almost always a bad idea to store value lists in a single field.

Comment: @Uueerdo changing database design is not a possible case for me... is there any way to do this without changing design?

Comment: @Lotharyx i want to add value to c_id column for a particular user_id... being new to mysql, i wasn't able to write queries to perform the required operations.

Comment: The update can be done with `CONCAT`, but the SELECT would be horrendously slow. Also, if you can't change the database structure, what data type is the `c_id` field currently; you may not be able to store multiple values.

Comment: its currently VARCHAR... i need to store multiple INT values @Uueerdo

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to add multiple values to your `c_id` field, simply because thats not how relational databases are meant to be used. If you want to link multiple rows from `table2` to one row of `table1` add rows for that.

e.g. to link two rows of 'table2' to one row of `table1`

table1:

```
id | link
-----------
1  | something
2  | some other
```

table2:

```
user_id | c_id
----------------
100     | 1
100     | 2
```

And please elaborate on

> also i need to write php APIs for the same

I don't believe anyone here can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: i want multiple values in c_id column for same user_id and i need to write php APIs to run these queries from an android application.

Comment: Go on and insert multiple rows for the same user_id with different c_id. And for your webservice you might want to ask google how to create json responses from php or how the create webservices using php. That a rather broad topic.